# How can I adjust the left margin in Visual Studio editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How can I adjust the left margin in the editor? I want to increase the space before actual text/code globally, obviously without inserting space or tab characters (in case you'd want to suggest that).  Please see the screenshot showing the desired effect below.

[image]